# System.NullPointerException Question (Basic)

Tags: apex, null-pointer, basics

I am new in coding. Currently, working on a nullpointerexception challenge on Apex.

Error: 
WarrantySummary: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.WarrantySummary: line 14, column 1

Code:

```
Integer warrantyDays; {

    if (myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c == null) {

    //below line is 14
            warrantyDays        = myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c.intValue() + 5;

    } else {

        warrantyDays        = myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c.intValue();
    }

    System.debug(warrantyDays);

   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: `warrantyDays = myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c == null ? 5 : myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c.intValue();` is the one line solution

Comment: thank you @cropready.  why did you use question mark?

Comment: It is the syntax of a ternary.  A convenient way to reduce a 4 line if else into one line.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c.intValue() + 5;
```

you are trying to get *intValue()* of null, which causes the error, just correct the code a little bit like:

```
if (myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c == null) {
    warrantyDays = 5;
} else {
    warrantyDays = myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mariia. It worked (y)